# TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures

Tags: ios, camera, ionic2

i am using camera plugin in my Ionic 2 app. It works fine in android. But it was throwing an error in IOS. i am getting this error after takes a picture using camera plugin. i am converting dataURI to a Blob: Could anyone suggest me where i am doing wrong?

This is an error: Xcode

> /www/build/polyfills.js:2:30128 ERROR: error JSON.stringify()ing
>   argument: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic
>   structures.

This one in console:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5
>   atob@[native code] dataURItoBlob

This is the code which convert dataURI to a Blob:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}
```